# Creating custom fields in xml file, for indixing in solr

Tags: xml, search, solr, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to index a xml file with modified fields however solr is giving error as #400 bad request, IO exception while reading response java.io.IOException.

Here is my xml file content.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <add>
      <doc>
        <field name="id">1</field>
        <field name="name">Atomic Counters</field>
        <field name="type">Accelerated Parallel Process</field>
        <field name="level">Beginner</field>

        <field name="Discription">If you use the method described above, only the "employee" element can use the specified complex type. Note that the child elements, "firstname" and "lastname", are surrounded by the <sequence> indicator. </field>

        <field name="open_cl">#1.0#1.1#1.2</field>
        <field name="version">1.1</field>
        <field name="date">1995-12-31T23:59:59Z</field>
        <field name="download1_link">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation</field>
        <field name="download2_link">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation</field>


      </doc>
    </add>
```

Also before this I have already added few lines in solr\example\solr\collection1\conf\schema.xml file

```
   <field name="download_link" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="download2_link" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <field name="version" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="open_cl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="level" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   
   <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Still no go..
Am I missing something..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like the URL is incorrect. Can you let us know which url you are trying to access while adding the xml. Also can you let us know the full stacktrace in the server side if any.

Comment: url which i have placed is working if pasted in a browsers, however this url is just for testing which I can replace it later. And about the error which is displayed in the command prompt for this file is like this.. POSTint file custom1.xml  <br> SimplePostTool: Warning:Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request <br> Simple Post Tool : Warning: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/upldate

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your xml is not a [well-formed document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)

Your line contains:

```
<field name="Discription">If you use ... by the <sequence> indicator. </field>
```

The `<sequence>` text should be escaped, like this:

```
<field name="Discription">If you use ... by the &lt;sequence&gt; indicator. </field>
```

Comment: I tried removing the sequence indicator "<sequence>" full word from the description field after your response and restarted the solr server and tried to index the file. Still the same error..

Comment: Could you give more details about how are you trying to add the document to the index? Are you adding it via http or solrj client? Can you share more details about the configuration? (schema) And finally, what does the solr logs say?

Comment: trying to add via command prompt using command java -jar post.jar *.xml. I am issuing this command after exampledocs dir. About schema.. I have just added few lines as shown above to the schema.xml file and can you please tell me where to find this logs

Answer (score 0):

thanks for responding to my quires..

I figured out my mistakes .. in fields i have mentioned Discription which should be description, download1_link should be written as download_link and finally I have not mentioned field type for date in schema file itself. I came to know this after **maraswrona** pointed for logs. 
I went solr admin dashboard and looked for logs and it cleared pointed the errors.

Once again Thanks to all of you...